# How to replace a column of a matrix with strings in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I currently have a matrix with numbers
totscoreT =

```
1.0000   28.3748
2.0000  -29.2461
3.0000    4.4731
4.0000   -6.2393
5.0000    2.6375
```

and would like to replace the first column with strings, such as
totscoreT =

```
team A   28.3748
team B  -29.2461
team C    4.4731
team D   -6.2393
team E    2.6375
```

I also need to be able to sort the rows after adding the string based on the values in the second column
ans =

```
1.0000    team A   28.3748
2.0000    team C    4.4731
3.0000    team E    2.6375
4.0000    team D   -6.2393
5.0000    team B  -29.2461
```

I know how to do this if I use 1=team A, 2=team B,..., but I would like to use names instead.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Cell arrays?

To do this you can populate the Cell array programmatically from your array, totscoreT, but for illustration I'll set it up manually:

```
C = {'team A', 'team B', 'team C', 'team D', 'team E' ;
     28.3748, -29.2461, 4.4731, -6.2393, 2.6375};
```

Then use the transpose to display as in your example:

```
>> C'
```

which gives:

```
'team A'    [ 28.3748]
'team B'    [-29.2461]
'team C'    [  4.4731]
'team D'    [ -6.2393]
'team E'    [  2.6375]
```

Then you can access the elements like:

```
>> C{1,2}

ans =

team B
```

or

```
>> C{2,2}

ans =

  -29.2461
```